# Caps lock indicator is ON after wake up

Tags: keyboard, indicator, suspend, capslock

Caps lock keyboard indicator is ON after waking up from suspension, but in fact it is turned OFF. So I have to press the CAPS LOCK button twice to make it normal. So the problem is with indicator only, capitalization works.

Notebook: HP Pavilion g6 1075er

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I came to Ubuntu a month ago, and I never experienced this problem in Windows.
Couldn't find relevant answer on web.

I have no changes for Caps lock button in keyboard layout settings.